# Is it possible to import something from a module, then use it from the Deno command prompt?

Tags: javascript, deno

Is it possible to import something from a module, then use it from the Deno command prompt?  If not, is there some other trick I can use to debug a module?

What I'm trying to do:

```
[phil@joey-mousepad ~/deno]$ deno
Deno 1.3.3
exit using ctrl+d or close()
> import { myFunction } from "./MyLibrary.js";
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at evaluate (rt/40_repl.js:60:36)
    at replLoop (rt/40_repl.js:160:15)
>
```

This works fine in my main program:

```
import { myFunction } from "./MyLibrary.js";
console.log(myFunction(1, “foo”, null));
```

But myFunction() has a bug or something.  I want to *quickly* try running it with a lot of different inputs *from the console*, rather than editing my main program and restarting Deno over and over.

At the moment I'm working with Deno, but the same issue applies to modules in a web page.  (Ideally I'll reuse some modules in Deno programs and web pages!)  When I'm working with a web page, I want to access modules from Chrome's JavaScript console.

Mozilla acknowledges this issue but does not offer a solution.  “and you won't be able to access them from the JavaScript console”  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

Comment: You probably want to search the Deno issue tracker. E.g. https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/1285, https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/2629, (basically, `from .. import ..` must, by definition, be loaded before any other code, which the REPL cannot enforce). However, have you tried a dynamic import instead, which is allowed anywhere at runtime and returns a promise? `import("./MyLibrary.js").then(... => ...)`

Answer (score 0):

This answer comes from one of the comments.  I added a few more details just to be complete.

```
import("./MyLibrary.js").then(module => window.MyLibrary = module);
```

followed by

```
MyLibrary.myFunction(2, "bar", undefined);
```

Deno will automatically tell you when it's loaded the module and it's safe to call the function.